# Дан массив символов, среди которых есть символ '#'.Определить, сколько символов стоит после него

Tags: python, массивы, строки

Python Дан массив символов, среди которых есть символ '#'.Определить, сколько символов стоит после него.

Comment: Ну так определяете.

Comment: Ну так не получается

Comment: Покажите ваши попытки. Которые "не получаются".  Или переименуйте вопрос в "напишите вместо меня программу".

Comment: p.s. получилось в итоге)0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вам понадобится

1. метод `.index('#')`, чтобы найти его позицию в списке
2. функция `len` для определения размера списка
3. вычитание для определения сколько символов осталось после `#`